# Valuation of an ideal in a two-dimensional regular local ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

Let $f,g$ be two coprime elements in the ring $K[[x,y]]$, with $K$ a field.
What is the smallest integer $n$ such that the inclusion of ideals $$(x^n)\subset (f,g)$$ holds in $K[[x,y]]$? Can we compute easily that integer? 
It's well known that $n$ is smaller or equal to the $x$-adic valuation of the $y$-resultant of the Weierstrass polynomials associated to $f$ and $g$. But can we do better in general? If yes, what is the geometrical interpretation of this integer in terms of the singularities of $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 1):

A few examples, not a general answer nor explanation in geometry (check my algebra):

1. f=y<sup>a</sup>-x<sup>b</sup>, g=y<sup>c</sup>-x<sup>d</sup> =>
   n=min { ab/(a,c), ad/(a,c), bd/(b,d), b<sup>2</sup>c/((b,d)(a,b<sup>2</sup>c/(b,d))) }; ord resultant = min{a,c}min{b,d} (here, (a,c)=gcd(a,c) etc)

   f=y<sup>3</sup>-x, g=y<sup>2</sup>-x => n=1, ord resultant=2

   f=y-x<sup>3</sup>, g=y-x<sup>2</sup> => n=2, ord resultant=2
2. f=y<sup>a</sup>-x<sup>b</sup>, g=y<sup>c</sup>x<sup>d</sup> => n depends on relative sizes of b,c and a,d

   f=y<sup>3</sup>-x, g=y<sup>3</sup>x => n=2, ord resultant=6